# How to find out why IIS worker process hangs on "Starting"?

Tags: iis, https, worker-process

My ASP.NET web application running in IIS always hangs on "Starting" state (IIS -> Server -> Worker Processes) after IIS reset.
Is this the case, every request to any url is loading forever.

The odd thing is that when I change my HTTPS binding port (Default Web Site -> Bindings) from 443 to 4434 and then back to 443 the worker process immediately goes to the "Running" state and every request is working (until I make a IIS reset again).

Another odd thing is that when I keep my HTTPS port at 4434 and do a IIS reset then the process is "Running" as well.

So could it have something to do with the HTTPS port 443?

How can I find out why my worker process hangs in the "Starting" state? I checked IIS logs but there is nothing eye-catching.

In the EventViewer there is only one message in that case: "A process serving application pool '[Pool name]' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service".

Is there any option to "trace" the app pool startup?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. A WCF service constructor was waiting infinite for a signalR connection.